# TOP Etch-a-sketch grid resizing

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to complete The Odin Project's Etch-a-Sketch challenge and am currently stuck with trying to resize the divs that make up the sketchpad. The app creates a 16x16 grid by default, and when pressing the erase button it asks for a number. It should then recreate the grid based on that number. However, after giving a number the size of the sketchpad is reduced. I have noticed that the number of empty divs created is always 256.
Link to codepen for clarification: https://codepen.io/eerolli/pen/abELQbp

Any help as to how I could get the size of the pad to stay the same regardless of the number of divs inside it is greatly appreciated.

Edit: It should probably be noted, that the app works fine when I enter a number equal to or lower than 16.

html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <title>Etch-a-Sketch</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="content">
        <h1>Etch-a-Sketch</h1>
        <div class="container">

        </div>
        <button>Erase</button>
    </div>
</body>
<script src="script.js"></script>
</html>
```

javascript:

```
let clear = document.querySelector("button");

//function to create a 16x16 grid
function createGrid(size){
    function resetSize(){
        clear.addEventListener('click', ()=>{
            let number = prompt("What size would you like the grid to be? (1-100)");
            container.style.gridTemplateRows = `repeat(${number}, 1fr)`;
            container.style.gridTemplateColumns = `repeat(${number}, 1fr)`;
        })
        
        
    }
    resetSize();

    let container = document.querySelector(".container");
    container.style.gridTemplateRows = `repeat(${size}, 1fr)`;
    container.style.gridTemplateColumns = `repeat(${size}, 1fr)`;
    
    for (let i = 0; i < size*size; i++) {
        
        let square = document.createElement("div");
        square.style.backgroundColor = "black";
        container.appendChild(square);

        //change background color of a square on hover
        square.addEventListener('mouseover', e=>{
            square.style.backgroundColor = "white";
        })


        //function to reset the grid
        function clearGrid(){
            clear.addEventListener('click', e=>{
                square.style.backgroundColor = "black"
           })
        }
        

        clearGrid();    
    }
}

createGrid(16);
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were super close ... you just need to call the create grid function again after the input prompt, and pass the new size/number the user entered as the argument ;D

---

Edit: Ah yeah, I didn't notice it got stuck in a loop. I've refactored a little and added a couple of comments, hopefully helps.

```js
let clear = document.querySelector("button");
let container = document.querySelector(".container"); // move container out here so can use everywhere

clear.addEventListener('click', ()=>{ // we only want to add this listener once
    resetSize()
})


function resetSize(){
        
        let number = prompt("What size would you like the grid to be? (1-100)");
        container.style.gridTemplateRows = `repeat(${number}, 1fr)`;
        container.style.gridTemplateColumns = `repeat(${number}, 1fr)`;
        createGrid(number); // call the createGrid function here and pass the number they entered as the argument. 
}
        
        
//function to create a 16x16 grid
function createGrid(size){

//    resetSize(); // get rid of this as this was causing it to show the prompt again each time


    container.style.gridTemplateRows = `repeat(${size}, 1fr)`;
    container.style.gridTemplateColumns = `repeat(${size}, 1fr)`;
    
    for (let i = 0; i < size*size; i++) {
        
        let square = document.createElement("div");
        square.style.backgroundColor = "black";
        container.appendChild(square);

        //change background color of a square on hover
        square.addEventListener('mouseover', e=>{
            square.style.backgroundColor = "white";
        })


        //function to reset the grid
        function clearGrid(){
            clear.addEventListener('click', e=>{
                square.style.backgroundColor = "black"
           })
        }
        

        clearGrid();    
    }
}

createGrid(16);
```

```css
body {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 0;
    min-height: 100vh;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}

.content {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
}

.container {
    width: 700px;
    height: 700px;
    display: grid;
    margin: 2rem;
    border: 2px solid burlywood;
}


h1 {
    text-align: center;
}

button {
    width: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
    <h1>Etch-a-Sketch</h1>
    <div class="container">
    </div>
    <button>Erase</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Oh man, such a simple solution and I missed it. Thanks for pointing it out. :D However, the prompt is now repeated despite giving a number. But I will try to solve it on my own for now.